# ActiveResource models + Sweepers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, activeresource

I've just started working with ActiveResource, and decided to cache a few bits of the model so I'm not hitting the api incessantly. Ok, fine.

I've looked into expiring caches, and decided to implement a sweeper (which I've not had to do yet). This isn't working.

AR model:

```
class Myresource < ActiveResource::Base
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
  define_model_callbacks :update

  "stuff"

  def current
    Rails.cache.fetch("/key/#{self.id}", :expires_in => 5.minutes) do
      Myresource.find(ID)
    end 
  end

end
```

Sweeper:

```
class MyresourceSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Myresource

  def after_update(myresource)
    expire_cache_for_myresource
  end

private
  def expire_cache_for_myresource
    Rails.cache.delete '/key/myresource.id'
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
cache_sweeper :myresource_sweeper
```

So having worked with AR and caches and Sweepers only a bit, I can't figure out where to look after trying various combos of things. I can set and expire from the console for a resource, but within the app, the cache gets set, but nothing I've done is triggering a delete.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you posted has a typo.  I kinda doubt this is your real problem, but for what it's worth, I think you meant to write your sweeper as follows:

```
class MyresourceSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Myresource

  def after_update(myresource)
    expire_cache_for_myresource(myresource)
  end

  private
  def expire_cache_for_myresource(myresource)
    Rails.cache.delete "/key/#{myresource.id}"
  end
end
```

E.g. in the original code you posted, you weren't passing the resource to the expire_cache_for_my_resource method, and therefore were expiring the same static key over and over again.

Comment: Yes, the typos were part of translating the actual code to something for example. It was a bit more complex than that, but I wasn't passing in the myresource properly (in a part I'd removed when I was still working with getting the hooks into the model which I didn't know I needed at the time, but anyway). Spotted as soon as I put this to the side and came back to it. thanks.